# Is it possible to have an object with retain count -1?

Tags: ios, memory-management, retaincount

I was refining my project about memory management.

I have logged all my retain count at dealloc method, and i faced it.

Is it possible?

```
2013-11-07 11:56:03.974 Project[2749:16403] unitId : -1
2013-11-07 11:56:04.231 Project[2749:16403] specId : -1
2013-11-07 11:56:04.566 Project[2749:16403] brickId : -1
2013-11-07 11:56:45.788 Project[2749:16403] brickRow : 0
```

Comment: According to your code it is. Probably not what you want though

Comment: [When should you use retain count?](http://whentouseretaincount.com)

Comment: Maybe it is, maybe it isn't, but who cares, because ARC exists! But, if you want a genuine answer, the retain count is probably 2147483647 (NSIntegerMax) and you got -1 because you printed the value with %i (try printing with %u). When the retain count is NSIntegerMax it means the object is immortal. Also, http://www.whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: remember `retainCount` is `NSUInteger` a.k.a `unsigned long`

Answer (score 3):

Retain counts are unsigned. If you log the maximum unsigned long value as a signed number, it will appear as -1. Your logging is written incorrectly.